# Object creating

Tags: java, object

Banal question, but why some people write so:

```
buttonCounter = new JButton("Click me");
panel.add(buttonCounter);
```

but right will be to write so:

```
JButton buttonCounter = new JButton("Click me");
panel.add(buttonCounter);
```

Where is a difference ? Or are they a different topics?

Comment: The first one is assigning to an existing variable. The second is declaring and initialising a new variable.

Comment: Please go through basic Java tutorial, this topic is covered in the very beginning chapters.

Comment: This is probably related to the scope of the variables (e.g. local, global).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buttonCounter = new JButton("Click me");
```

would mean `buttonCounter` is declared somewhere else (otherwise the code wouldn't compile).

That is :

```
JButton buttonCounter;
....
// some lines of code not referencing `buttonCounter`
....
buttonCounter = new JButton("Click Me")
```

Another way to declare & initialize the variable would be:

```
JButton buttonCounter = new JButton("Click me");
```